# Python3 WSGI Shows bytestring in Browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am building a web application in Python3 with mod_wsgi. Everything works well without errors, except I keep getting:

b'

in my response that is delivered to the browser. Also, anything that is escaped with the "\" character shows in the response as well.

Here is an example of a function that returns content:

```
def index(self):
    # self.default_encode = 'UTF-8'
    self.header("Content-type", "text/html;")
    return_string = Index.index()
    self.header("Content-Length", str(len(return_string)))
    return return_string.encode(self.default_encode)
```

Here is how I am returning my response to the browser:

```
def __iter__(self):
    x = self.delegate()
    self.start(self.status, self._headers)

    if isinstance(x, str):
        return iter(repr([x]))
    else:
        return iter(repr(x))
```

I am encoding everything as UTF-8 and am unsure why I can't make this go away. I have searched on SO, Google, and Bing and have tried casting as bytes(). It may be useful, but this started to occur when I switched from libapache2-mod-wsgi to libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I needed to:

```
yield return_string.encode(self.default_encode)
```

rather than:

```
return return_string.encode(self.default_encode)
```